# make an app as system modal dialogue

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm trying to create an application which will stop all other phone functionalities until user responds to a certain event on my application. For example, the phone is suspended until user responds to a message box(`System modal dialogue box`). Is this possible??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um no. WP7 OS does a pretty good job at stoping virues or spammers. The OS will NEVER allow you todo this.

Comment: I think thats the reason WP7 is running low on apps.. I just wanted to create an alarm app which will keep on ringing until user plays a simple Q&A game.

Comment: Sounds annoying. I do not know of any phone OS that will stop your phone features.